# Javascript Parse Facebook Login Issue

Tags: javascript, facebook, parse-platform, oauth

I am getting:

> Given URL is not whitelisted in Client OAuth Settings: This redirect
>   failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client
>   OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add
>   all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

I have set the example.com/app in Site Url in FB settings. I have the right Parse appId, JSKey. I have put facebook auth details in parse, and parse confirmed it recognized them. I have, in fb, Client OAuth and web oauth enabled.

It requires me, Valid OAuth redirect URIs, so I have put

> example.com, example.com/app, example.com/app/page.html.

Nothing fixes the error. I have tried every tweak and every combination. I tried adding and removing the app domain. Tweaking with the example.com/app app folder in Site URL. Maybe not include it.

Nothing helps, I'm stuck, what am I doing wrong? (I'm doing exactly the same on localhost btw, and it works)

Comment: What is the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in your login dialog call?

Comment: It's an encoded url, when I put it through a url decoder, something like this comes out: http://static.ak.facebook.com/connect/xd_arbiter/TlA_zCeMkxl.js?version=41#cb=f3d15b6718&domain=example.com&origin=http%3A%2F%example.com%2Ff1621b2b4&relation=parent

Comment: did you solved this problem ?

Comment: I have not. And there's just not clue to what's wrong.

Answer (score 23):

After the new Developer portal updates, the OAuth redirect URIs can now be found under

> **Products > Facebook Login > Settings > Client OAuth Settings**

or you can access via url: 
**https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{appid}/fb-login/**

Comment: Yes! this answer is latest :)

Comment: Thanks. Took me 1 hour to figure this out. I didn't even know what to Google :D

Comment: Yeah this is kind of hidden in their new UI, its not very sensibly placed considering its an app setting - albeit involved as facebook login not sure why its the odd duck out...

Answer (score 17):

I'm also faced this problem.  On my situation site url writen with "**www**".
If you site adress http://example.com then http://www.example.com is different website for facebook sdk. 
In facebook application console go

> Settings > Advanced > Client OAuth Settings >Valid OAuth redirect
>   URIs

Write here **www** version also. It must work

Comment: Doesn't. I wrote both domains, in App Domains and in Valid OAuth redirects URLs and still same error message.

Comment: this has moved as per Rich S's comment

Answer (score 5):

I also faced the error while trying to integrate Facebook login on my localhost in a Rails app and fixed it by removing the trailing slash from the URL specified in **Valid OAuth redirect URIs**

It was: `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback/`

It was supposed to be `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback`

Thanks to @CBroe [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169276/javascript-parse-facebook-login-issue#comment56101720_34169276) to check the redirect_uri and found that in the URL in the browser's address bar it was

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=<my_app_client_id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback&response_type=code&scope=email&state=afcbee26c2ce5077f844ce864780082991d36e6c3e10863a`

and in my **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** it was mentioned `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback/` (note the trailing slash at the end)

Hope this helps anyone facing this problem with the URL problem I had.

Comment: Looks like Facebook is now automatically adding the trailing slash when you enter in redirect urls

Answer (score 1):

I've just had the issue (November 5, 2017), after years of it working properly.

My issue was that the callback url was in the wrong place in the Facebook admin page. You need to put it in the "**Facebook Login**" "**Products**" (in the left menu, in the Facebook admin console, NOT in the "Advanced settings":

```
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{{your FB app id}}/fb-login/settings/
```

You need to put the port number if you have one, e.g. in my case http://local.dishly.menu:3000/