# URL BLOCKED: Facebook login with php sdk

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, localhost, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to test my web app having facebook login facility in localhost.
But I am getting the following error

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

I had given app domain as localhost and site url as http://localhost in the FB App's settings.

My code

```
  if (isset($_GET['code'])) {


        header('Location: http://localhost');
    }

    // getting basic info about user
    try {
        $profile_request = $fb->get('/me?fields=name,first_name,last_name');
        $profile = $profile_request->getGraphNode()->asArray();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        session_destroy();
        // redirecting user back to app login page

        header('Location: http://localhost');

        exit;
    }
              :
              :
              :
{
    // if not logged in display

    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://localhost/index.php');
    echo "<div style=\"padding-top:5%;\"><h1>why so serious?</h1>
                    <span><a href=\"".$loginUrl ."\" class=\"email\">LOGIN WITH FACEBOOK</a></span></div>

                    ";

}
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169276/javascript-parse-facebook-login-issue) and [it's duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34477847/facebook-login-with-javascript-sdk-error-redirect-uri-not-whitelisted) could be related. The 2nd question has several helpful links.

Comment: @Terminus It doesnt solved the problem actually.  But was helpful +1

Comment: Products -> Facebook Login. If that isn’t there already, you need to add it first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution. Thanks @CBroe

Under the `PRODUCTS` heading, Select `Facebook Login`
Now give `http://localhost` under `Valid OAuth redirect URI`
Then save changes

[image]