# Ionic facebook login for native

Tags: facebook-graph-api, ionic-framework

I have implemented the facebook login for my ionic application, which works perfectly when run on web. When i build the application, create an apk of the same, and try to run on my mobile device, nothing happens.

The login is:

```
openFB.login(
            function (response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected') {
                    console.log('Facebook login succeeded, got access token: ', response); 

                    openFB.api({
                        path: '/me',
                        success: function (data) {
                            console.log("My Data", data);
                            userData.name = data.name;
                            userData.picture = 'http://graph.facebook.com/' + data.id + '/picture?type=small';
                            localStorageService.set('user', userData);
                            $timeout(function() {
                                $state.go('app.home');
                            }, 0);
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                            console.log("Error here:", error);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('Facebook login failed: ' + response);
                }
            }, { scope: 'email, public_profile' });
```

Have used openFB for the login. After clicking, following popup comes up.

[image]

After clicking the okay, nothing gets logged. No console message.

Can some one help me for finding out this issue, where i am not able to do the facebook login, when run on actual device.

Comment: debug your code using chrome. Then if you cant figure it out yourself, include relevant code and error messages here . Without it, there is no way anyone can help.

Comment: @raj : Updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist the redirect url. You can set it in

**Products > Facebook Login > Settings > Client OAuth Settings**

Take a look into this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169276/javascript-parse-facebook-login-issue).

Comment: Have already tried that. Since i am running my app locally, i have mentioned http://localhost in Valid OAuth redirect URIs.

Answer (score 0):

please set redirect URI in 
Products > Facebook Login > Settings > Client OAuth Settings

http://localhost/callback

please follow the below procedure to register your app in facebook developer site
https://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/ionic-facebook-integration.html

and use the below code to complete the procedure of facebook login

```
$cordovaOauth.facebook("appId", ["email", "public_profile"]).then(function(result) {
//alert(JSON.stringify(result));
//$localStorage.accessToken = result.access_token;
$http.get("https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me", {
    params: {
        access_token: result.access_token,
        fields: "id,name,gender,location,email,picture,relationship_status",
        format: "json"
    }
}).then(function(result) {
    // alert(JSON.stringify(result));
    $scope.loginflowusingsociallogin(result.data.email);
}, function(error) {
    alert("There was a problem getting your profile.  Check the logs for details.");
    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
});
});
```

i used Oauth 2.0 authentication for ionic.

Comment: This function for login is not working. Have uncommented the alert, to check whether i am getting a response or not. No alert is getting displayed.

Comment: is it open facebook login page or not

Comment: its open facebook login page

Comment: then will it showing any error messages after successful login   
 also check app review in developer.facebook.com and check the Approved Items if all are active or not if any one is missing please unable it and enable make app public in same settings page

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](http://tphangout.com/using-facebook-graph-api-in-your-ionic-2-apps/) code and worked fine for me

Comment: I am using ionic, not ionic 2. Anything related to ionic